# how to disable previous dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, fullcalendar

I am trying to create a calendar in JavaScript and I am trying to disable the previous day from today.

```
for (var c = 0; c < 42 - r; c++) {
        var v = e[c].day;
        var m = g(new Date(t, n - 1, v))
          ? `<div id="${v}/${n}/${t}" class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">`
          : z(new Date(t, n - 1, v))
          ? `<div class="past">`
          : `<div id="${v}/${n}/${t}" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">`;
        l.append(
          m +
            "" +
            '<span class="month">' +
            i[n - 1] +
            "</span>" +
            "" +
            v +
            "</div>"
        );
    }
```

So here v is a day, n is a month and t is a year. And here is g and z functions:

```
function g(e) {
    return y(new Date()) == y(e);
  }
  function z(e) {
    return y(new Date()) > y(e);
  }
function y(e) {
    return e.getFullYear() + "/" + (e.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + e.getDate();
  }
```

So I am expection to have previous dates like this: `<div class="past">`, today is like this: `<div id="${v}/${n}/${t}" class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">` and future is like this: `<div id="${v}/${n}/${t}" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">`

But what I am having is `<div class="past">`, `<div id="${v}/${n}/${t}" class="today" type="button" onclick="addRow(this)">`, `<div class="past">`

So where do you think I am making things wrong?

Comment: What does `y` do?  If it computes the year then yeah, the year of tomorrow is probably the same as the year of today, in most cases.  What if you remove all the `y` calls from g and z.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add it. Check out the edited question please

Comment: It would help greatly if you used descriptive variable names so the code was semantic. The use of chained conditional operators instead of *if..else* makes the code much more difficult to understand than it should be. Also, this isn't using the fullcalendar library so the tag is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "2021/8/9" is greater than "2021/8/10" when you do string comparison (9 is greater than 1).  You need those month/day values properly zero padded (2021/08/09) vs (2021/08/10).

Try

```
function y(e) {
    return e.getFullYear()
      + "/" + String(e.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0") 
      + "/" + String(e.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
}
```